# How can I listen to messages from an DLL in c#

Tags: c#, forms, dll, listener, message

I have a device that is controlled by standard win32 dlls.  The device responses are sent back through an application window handle (required when connected).
Right now, the only way I have to look at the messages is by overriding the WndProc inside the form, which is quite limiting.

My original intention was to isolate as much as possible the device bare handling from the application by placing everything inside a dll, but this dependency is keeping me from achieving it.

I need some sort of hook that will allow me to peek at the messages being received by the Form (a la WndProc) but from my dll.  All I have seen shows hooks from within the same form, not from a dll.

Oh, by the way, I understand hooks are WPF compatible also, and that is a requirement here as well.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Nope, that's the way to do it.  There certainly is no reason why you couldn't just create the form instance in the DLL.  And a form class is just a class like any other .NET class.  It doesn't have to be a visible window, as long as the device code can find it.

Comment: Here is the thing.  The device will only send its messages if the window is the main form of the application, so it had to be created using Application.Run or shown using ShowDialog, which is why I cannot hide it, create it, or derive from it from within the class.  I tried it using wndprc and the messages simply stopped showing up.  Oh, by the way, I tried IMessageFilter, and it would skip a couple of messages for no particular reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMessageFilter only gives you posted messages, not sent messages.  There is of course little you can do if the device code insists on using the app's main window.  You'll need to add a public method to let the main app tell you what its main window's Handle value is.  You can then derive your own class from NativeWindow to subclass that main window and spy on its messages.  Use the AssignHandle() method and override WndProc() to snoop.  Be sure to call DefWndProc() for any messages that are not device related.  You also need to detect WM_CLOSE so you can un-subclass the window, call ReleaseHandle().

Comment: Your suggestion is what looks to be the way to go.  I will give it a try.  I got it working with a hidden control, but it will probably wont work for WPF so I will try this instead.  Thank you!  Be right back with the results...

Comment: It will work for WPF as well, it also uses a regular Windows window.  Just a bit more hassle to get the Handle.

Comment: It worked.  Had to use the WindowInteropHelper to get the IntPtr from the WPF Window but besides that, it was flawless.  Thanks a million!  I was adviced before about this alternative, but it was missing the AssignHandle requirement, which was obviously essential.  Again, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a method inside the DLL that you call from WndProc?

```
//In the DLL
public bool HandleMessage(/*args go here that I forget*/) {
    if(/*message is for me*/) {
        //handle it
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//in WndProc
if(MyObject.HandleMessage(/*args*/)) {
    return true;
}
//do whatever else
```

Comment: I am trying to isolate the code from the application window because not all devices i am using require this sort of callback methodology.  The class implements a standard interface that is consumed by the application, so this will affect the design pattern.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Got it!

Just in case someone else falls into this sort of pit. It may be dirty, but it works.

I created a Control class within my dll and attached it to the main window I receive during instantiation. Within my Control class, which I had to make public for it to be attached to the form, I inserted the WndProc overriden function. It worked! It is a mix of both worlds but it started capturing the device´s messages from withing my dll!

Thanks for the suggestions to all!
I have to wait a couple of hours before I close this question